# Memory Fragmentation with byte[] in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, memory-management, memory-fragmentation

The C#/.NET application I am working on makes use of huge byte arrays and is having memory fragmentation issues. Checked memory usage using CLRMemory

[image: please ref the image for LOH and Free Space]

The Code we use is as follows

```
PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument = new PdfLoadedDocument("myLoadedDocument.pdf");

// Operations on pdf document

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    loadedDocument.Save(stream);
    loadedDocument.Close(true);
    return stream.ToArray(); //byte[]
}
```

And we use similar code at multiple places across our application and we call this in loop for generating bulk audits ranging from a few 100's to 10000's

1. Now is there a better way to handle this to avoild fragmentation

And as part of audits, we also download large files from Amazon S3 using the following code

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(_accessKey, _secretKey, _region))
{
   var getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest();
   getObjectRequest.BucketName = "bucketName";
   getObjectRequest.Key = "keyName";

   using (var downloadStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
       using (var response = await client.GetObjectAsync(getObjectRequest))
       {
           using (var responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
           {
               await responseStream.CopyToAsync(downloadStream);
           }
           return downloadStream.ToArray(); //byte[]
       }
   }
}
```

2. Is there a better alternative to download large files without them moving to LOH which is taking a toll with Garbage Collector

Comment: Maybe run the GC before writing data to minimize the fragmentation.

Comment: @jdweng, We call this in a loop, calling GC every time might heavily impact CPU performance as all other resources will be held during this operation

Comment: Well just call the GC before the loop.  The using statements should dispose object so as long as the enough continuous memory is cleared for the largest object in the loop you shouldn't get fragmented.

Comment: I am afraid that might not help as the fragmentation is occurring due to the inner logic and we have dispose for every IDisposable object. So calling GC outside may have zero to negligible impact. And calling GC explicitly isn't always recommended.

Answer (score 2):

There's two different things here:

1. the internals of `MemoryStream`
2. the usage of `.ToArray()`

For what happens inside `MemoryStream`: it *is* implemented as a simple `byte[]`, but you can mitigate a lot of the overhead of that by using `RecyclableMemoryStream` instead via the `Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream` nuget package, which re-uses buffers between independent usages.

For `ToArray()`, frankly: *don't do that*. When using vanilla `MemoryStream`, the better approach is `TryGetBuffer(...)`, which gives you the *oversized* backing buffer, along with the start/end tokens:

```cs
if (!memStream.TryGetBuffer(out var segment))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to obtain data segment; oops?");
// see segment.Offset, .Count, and .Array
```

It is then your job to *not look outside those bounds*. If you want to make that easier: consider treating the segment as a span (or memory) instead:

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<byte> muchSafer = segment;
// now you can't read out of bounds, and you don't need to apply the offset yourself
```

This `TryGetBuffer(...)` approach, however, does not work well with `RecyclableMemoryStream` - as it makes a defensive copy to prevent problems with independent data; in *that* scenario, you should treat the stream simply *as a stream*, i.e. `Stream` - just write to it, rewind it (`Position = 0`), and have the consumer read from it, then dispose it when they are done.

---

As a side note: when reading (or writing) using the `Stream` API: consider using the array-pool for your scratch buffers; so instead of:

```cs
var buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{...}
```

instead try:

```cs
var buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(1024);
try
{
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {...}
}
finally
{
    ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
}
```

---

In more advanced scenarios, it may be wise to use the *pipelines* API rather than the *stream* API; the point here is that pipelines allows *discontiguous* buffers, so you never need ridiculously large buffers even when dealing with complex scenarios. This is a niche API, however, and has very limited support in public APIs.

Comment: @HattedRooster Simple answer is: think about each and every line of code: what it does, why it does it, is that the best way, what are the implications; rather than what most people seem to do which is copy-pasta from [so]